# Colab set project folder to default in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have started a ML course and using google colab. I want to organise all the course datasets within a folder on google drive.

1 - How can map the project folder as the default directory instead of /content within colab

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive',force_remount=True)
project = 'gdrive/MyDrive/Tensorflow-lazyprogrammer'
```

2 - If i'm download a dataset from a weblink, how can set the command to download the dataset to the default directory or subdir.
I like to download the data from this link to the Tensorflow-lazyprogrammer folder within MyDrive

```
!wget https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/arrhythmia/arrhythmia.data
```

[image]